# Handle mulitple clients with one server?

Tags: java, network-programming

What do I have to do to my code so that multiple clients can connect to the server it? please explain because I'm fairly new to network programming.

ServerMethod.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class serverMethod {
    public void lookForConnection() {
        Socket connection;
        {
            try {
                System.out.print("Program running...");
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
                while (true) {
                    connection = serverSocket.accept();
                    if (connection != null) {
                        System.out.print("Connected Succesfully!");
                        System.out.print(connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//class that executes the server

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        serverMethod Server = new serverMethod();
        Server.lookForConnection();
    }
}
```

Client method

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class clientMethod {

    public String serverIP;
    public String password;
    public Socket connection;

    public void Client(String host) {
        serverIP = host;
    }

    public void startRunning() {
        try {
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Attempting connection...");
            System.out.print("Please provide the admin password: ");
            password = console.next();
            if (password.compareTo("root") == 0) {
                connectToServer();
            }

        } catch (EOFException eofException) {
            System.out.print("\n Client terminated the connection");
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void connectToServer() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Attempting connection...");
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);
        System.out.println("Connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }
}
```

class that launches client

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        clientMethod client = new clientMethod();
        client.Client("192.1xx.x3.x7"); //for posting purposes, replaced the ip
        client.startRunning();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make a thread to handle the input.

Comment: You must create a new `Thread` for each client you get connecting to the server to handle the `input / output`

Comment: How do create a new thread for each client? Do you have an article or anything I can read to learn more?@3kings